# Why does mysqli stop after bind_result?

Tags: php, mysqli

Something that works fine on my own machine is failing on the production server.

The following code outputs "**24**" and "**Begin try branch**" and that's it. It stops after that. On my own machine, the variables are bound and I can go on using `$recPhotos->fetch()` etc.

Problem occurs here:

```
$recPhotos = GetPhotos($_SESSION['album_uid'], $getVipImages, $arrPaginationParams["currentPage"], $arrPaginationParams["photosPerPage"]);
try 
{   
    echo($recPhotos->affected_rows);  // Outputs '24'
    echo("Begin try branch");
    $recPhotos->bind_result($file_name, $is_vip);   
    echo("End try branch");
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo 'Exception caught: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
echo("Continue");
```

The called function is as follows:

```
// Get photos from database
function GetPhotos($album_uid, $getVipImages,$page, $rows)
{
    $objMySqli = GetDbConnection();
    $page = ($page - 1) * 24;

    if ($objMySqliQuery = $objMySqli->prepare("SELECT file_name, is_vip from album_pic where album_uid = ? AND is_vip = ? OR is_vip = 'N' order by is_vip DESC, file_name ASC LIMIT ?,? ;")) 
    {
        $objMySqliQuery->bind_param('ssss', $album_uid, $getVipImages, $page, $rows); 
        $objMySqliQuery->execute();
        $objMySqliQuery->store_result();    
        return $objMySqliQuery;
    }
    else 
    {
        // Error
        printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $objMySqli->error);
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Strangely enough, if I try to output some rows **INSIDE** the function, it works (I get 24 rows, as expected)

```
// Get photos from database
function GetPhotos($album_uid, $getVipImages,$page, $rows)
{
    $objMySqli = GetDbConnection();
    $page = ($page - 1) * 24;

    if ($objMySqliQuery = $objMySqli->prepare("SELECT file_name, is_vip from album_pic where album_uid = ? AND is_vip = ? OR is_vip = 'N' order by is_vip DESC, file_name ASC LIMIT ?,? ;")) 
    {
        $objMySqliQuery->bind_param('ssss', $album_uid, $getVipImages, $page, $rows); 
        $objMySqliQuery->execute();

        $objMySqliQuery->bind_result($col1, $col2);
        while ($objMySqliQuery->fetch()) 
        {
            printf("%s %s\n", $col1, $col2); // This will be executed 24 times
        }               
    }
    else 
    {
        // Error
        printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $objMySqli->error);
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Tip: echo is not a function. You don't need to use brackets on it. e.g. `echo 'Hi'` is identical to `echo('Hi')`.

Comment: In your 'working' snippet, you removed the `store_result` call, try removing it for the non-working snippet and see if it works. Even if it doesn't I'd recommend against not using it, as buffers the entire result set, which if large could impact performance.

Comment: Thanks for your tips guys. 

@MikePurcell: I tried removing the `store_result` but that did not work. As I said, this works without a hitch on my local machine... so I infer that it must be something in the production server settings or something. I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the error log? Maybe the production machine doesn't have the mysqli module compiled.

Comment: @MikePurcell: I had the same tought yesterday. I'm no PHP guru but phpinfo() gives me a bunch of info about mysqli so I guess it IS installed. Further, if mysqli was not there, it would fail sooner, wouldn't it? Thanks for your continued input.

Comment: Are you certain there is data in the production database you are querying? Does the 2nd snippet trick work on production as well? If you want to find out where your error log is, you can visit the page which outputs `phpinfo()` and search for `error_log`, then log into the production machine and tail the error log to see what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: @MikePurcell: Hi Mike. Yep, there is stuff in the DB: affected_rows display '24'. And the 2nd snippet works nicely on the production server. My host does not provide an error log so I made this: `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);`
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`
`ini_set('log_errors',TRUE);`
`ini_set('html_errors',FALSE);`
`ini_set('error_log','/home/kerans/public_html/test/error_log.txt');`
`ini_set('display_errors',FALSE);`
But the log stays blank, as does the page. Now I'd be glad only to know what the error is!

Comment: Page is probably blank because the httpd doesn't have write access to your log file as it is set, and php is complaining about it. Try putting it in the /tmp directory, just so we can see what's going on.

Comment: @MikePurcell: I think the httpd does have write access. I provoked an error in my code (undeclared var) and it got logged fine. BTW, Stack Overflow is asking me to move this discussion to 'chat', whatever that is. Would you be OK with that? Again, thanks for your patience on this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11033/discussion-between-mike-purcell-and-kerans)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing where you going wrong is assuming that the connection stays open after you return from the function GetPhotos()

Basically you are opening the connection on the line:

```
$objMySqli = GetDbConnection();
```

When the function returns, the object $objMySqli goes out of scope. After that PHP is allowed to destroy the object (which will also close the connection) whenever it feels like it. On your machine it just happens to stay connected long enough to get the rows of data. On a production machine (which has less free memory) the garbage collector acts much faster.

What you should do is either:

1) Not use store_result() as it's a lot more efficient to copy the results out, rather than keep SQL connections open just to hold the data.

2) Open the connection in the outer function and pass it in as a parameter to the GetPhotos() function.

Also you should be explicitly closing the connection, rather than just letting it be closed either by the PHP garbage collector or when the script finishes.